# How to communicate between browser tabs/windows?

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I am bulding chat application. To open chat user clicks button and opens iframe with chat. At this momment I set cookie with user_id in main window. In chat application in iframe I have timmer with callback which check if cookie was set. If cookie was set then application opens new chat with user by user_id and remove cookie. It works well.

But when user opens 2 and more tabs then aplication opens chat only in one tab beacouse cookie was deleted in that tab. I can remove cookie with delay, but I didn't that way.

How can I find solution of this problem?

Comment: Could you provide us with some code so we might get a better vision about your question?

Answer (score 3):

[HTML5 LocalStorage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) (and its associated event, `storage`) is useful for communicating between browser windows from the same domain.  Be aware though, that browsers like IE and chrome will trigger the event differently.  In particular, Chrome will only trigger the event if the storage was changed by a different window while IE will trigger the event on every change regardless.

```
if (window.addEventListener) {
  window.addEventListener("storage", handle_storage, false);
} else {
  window.attachEvent("onstorage", handle_storage);
};

function handle_storage(e) {
  if (!e) { e = window.event; }
}
```